# ruby/mysql mysql_adapter.rb:505:in 'real_connect': cant convert String to Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, typeerror

I came in this morning, fired up my app in the same way as usual, and started getting this error.  Since then, I have been down every road I can conceive - to the point of removing and reinstalling every piece of ruby/rails software on my machine, including mysql.  I have stripped my application down to just the following.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'active_record'

class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

end

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    :adapter     => "mysql",
    :host        => "192.168.254.22",  (I've also tried 127.0.0.1)
    :port        => "3306",
    :database    => "databasethingie",
    :username    => "root",
    :password    => "rootpassword"
)
```

job = Job.find(:first)
This is on a windows box running instant rails 2.0.

I still get the errors:

```
c:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:505:in `real_connect': can't convert String into Integer (TypeError)
        from c:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:505:in `connect'
        from c:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:183:in `initialize'
        from c:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:88:in `new'
        from c:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:88:in `mysql_connection'
        from c:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:292:in `send'
        from c:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:292:in `connection='
        from c:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:260:in `retrieve_connection'
        from c:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:78:in `connection'
        from c:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:2693:in `quoted_table_name'
        from c:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:1469:in `construct_finder_sql'
        from c:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:1341:in `find_every'
        from c:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:1303:in `find_initial'
        from c:/InstantRails/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.1.0/lib/active_record/base.rb:534:in `find'
        from tmp.rb:17
```

I've seen posts about this that refer to a bug that was fixed way back in 1.5.2 days, but I'm up-to-date.  2.1.2, etc.  What is going on here?  I had wondered if this was related to recent changes to the database configuration (granting full rights to root) but the reinstall would seem to prove otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
:port => 3306
```